# How do I reverse an unconfirmed transaction to the original wallet

Tags: blockchain, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

Is there an easy to understand step by step guide I can execute to create a double spend and get the unconfirmed transaction reversed back into the original wallet so I can resend it with a higher fee and get it delivered?

Comment: You can try sending the same amount but this time with a little more free than usual so that this transaction gets confirmed faster than the previous one.

Comment: I dont know how wallets work but he should make sure to reuse previously sent outputs, to invalidate older transaction.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy to understand step by step guide

No. There is no **easy to understand** guide if you do not understand the underlying  processes.

> I can execute to create a double spend and get the unconfirmed
>   transaction reversed back into the original wallet

The transactions can not be "reversed back" and are not going "to/from the wallet".

> so I can resend it with a higher fee and get it delivered?

The doublespending transaction is the transaction which uses the same input set, but has another outputs/fees. You do not need to do two steps (a) reverse original transaction (b) send another transaction with higher fees, because this is one step.

As far as I know, some wallets contain Replace-By-Fee features, but I use my own program. It is not "easy-to-understand", but it works

Answer (score 0):

No, but if your concern only is to make the transaction to go through you can google for transaction priority services.

several miners offer services to pay extra fees to expediate transactions that would otherwise be stuck with too low fee.

Answer (score 0):

you can not reverse sent transaction. It is in mem pool and waiting to be picked up.
you can send double spend transaction with higher fee to another nodes, if your first transaction is not picked by miners yet there is very very low chance your new transaction will be processed first as miners might pick with high fee.

Eventually only one tx will be processed.

Answer (score -1):

No. That type of double-spend will produce a conflict and will get your node DoS banned assuming that you've already broadcasted an earlier transaction that spent the UTXOs.

Unfortunately, you will not be able to use RBF to doublespend.

Comment: downvoted. the answer is wrong

Comment: my answer is based on src/validation.cpp:653 in bitcoin-core, unless I misunderstood something. Double-spending an already spent output will cause a transaction to be included in setConflict, so the DoS score will be incremented for the node that relays the conflict tx.